# Should I be using the test classes on Android Studio?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

Should I be using the test classes on Android Studio for my small application?
What can unit testing tell me that I can't already see in logs when I run the App? Can you give an example of something I should test by writing testing code rather than just manually testing stuff on my device?

Answer (score 0):

Well, by using for instance JUnit you can test for much more cases (especially edge cases since you are able to use dummy data for the tests). 
You can also test much more efficient. Let's assume you've manually tested for 30 minutes. If you change some small detail you would essentially need to test for another 30 minutes to make sure that the change didn't influence the other components.

But let's say you are using UnitTesting. Well, after changing some small detail you just run the test again and the outcome should be the same.

If you plan to release the app I would definetly make use of the test classes.

Take a look at this article for more details: https://www.seguetech.com/why-mobile-application-testing-important/